# I cannot resize columns in any program except Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I experimented with Winbuilder, and after some time I noticed that 
I cannot resize columns in uTorrent, move bookmarks and bookmark folders in Chrome, 
then cannot resize columns in Comodo Programs Manager - everywhere!
For example , in uTorrent, columns just froze where I left them last time.
But Windows Explorer is functioning properly.
Where should I search for this problem? I think this is something wrong with registry, but regular registry cleaners do not help.
And I cannot even resize a columns in regedit - this is a real hell!

Comment: Why do you suspect a registry problem? If this is in fact the case, restore to a previous point in time where your registry was fine.

Comment: unfortunatelly, there is no restore point - to many updates went since then, before I noticed this problem. Windows stores most of the settings in registry and there are some common settings to all programs, that, as I suspect have a place here. Because the problem is in multiple programs, that are not a part of Windows and even in some programs like Regedit. But explorer runs fine.

Comment: well, may be it is some windows shared component is corrupted, that is used for many programs to display and sort columns, but I am not a programmer )) - so I do not know what component can it be.

Comment: yet one thing - I know that is possibly to use Windows 7 recovery options directly from bootable Windows CD or something (non system restore), but I never used them, and I do not know  how to use them. And I do not know where the problem can hide

Comment: Does it work as expected in Safe Mode?

Comment: I will try to do this from boot CD, a little later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by running the Windows System File Checker utility sfc.exe and see if it finds a corrupt system file.

Can we assume you have used a good anti-malaware tool or two( or three)  to assure it is not an infection of some sort?

Comment: ok, I will try to run SFC. I did not used any antimalware, but I do not install to many unsafe stuff like cracks, etc. I only install software from known or oficial sites. And I use Comodo Antivirus. Problems started since I experimented with Winbuilder - WinPE based Live CD creation program, that performs quite non trivial manipulation with data, so I think, that it caused that problem. No unsafe software was installed then, at least lately. And I use only Chrome web browser, that is the most secure.

Comment: Even "good" sites can be compromised.  Malwarebytes, Spybot and Adaware would be useful just in case

Comment: I am going to try it today's evening (in about 8-10 hrs) from boot CD, With Windows 7 RE and DaRT 7 onboard ))) - It booted yesterady from USB, just 450 MB, but very slowly, and DaRT connected to Windows instalation properly, but I had to go to sleep. Here, below it was suggested to try SFC.EXE, but from running Windows it do not repair everything, as it reported. Should I try something else from DaRT 7 tools, that could possibly help ?

Comment: ogh my god - it is alrady working !! Yeess !! )), but evening time I will do that anyway - to be sure, that everything is fine.